# ValueError: Requesting 5-fold cross-validation but provided less than 5 examples for at least one class

Tags: python, scikit-learn, svm, cross-validation, text-classification

I have been training a text classifier to then later use to predict characters of a TV show. So far, my code looks like:

```
vectorizer = TfidfVectorizer(ngram_range=(1,2),min_df=0.001, max_df=0.75,stop_words='English')
X = vectorizer.fit_transform(data['text'])
y = data['character']
print(X.shape, y.shape) #prints (5999, 1429) (5999,)

# get baseline performance
kf = KFold(n_splits=5)
most_frequent = DummyClassifier(strategy='most_frequent')
print(cross_val_score(most_frequent , X, y=y, cv=kf, n_jobs= -1, scoring="accuracy").mean())

# fine-tune classifier
base_clf = CalibratedClassifierCV(cv=kf, base_estimator=LogisticRegression(n_jobs= -1, solver='lbfgs' ))

param_grid = {'base_estimator__C': [0.01, 0.05, 0.1, 0.5, 1.0, 10, 20, 50],
'base_estimator__class_weight': ['balanced', 'auto']}

search = GridSearchCV(base_clf, param_grid, cv=kf, scoring='f1_micro')
search.fit(X, y)

# use best classifier to get performance estimate
clf = search.best_estimator_.base_estimator
print(cross_val_score(clf, X, y=y, cv=kf, n_jobs= -1, scoring='f1_micro').mean())
```

However, I keep getting the following error:

```
ValueError                                Traceback (most recent call last)
/var/folders/fv/h7n33cb5227g4t5lxym8g_800000gn/T/ipykernel_2208/2611717736.py in <module>
      6 
      7 search = GridSearchCV(base_clf, param_grid, cv=kf, scoring='f1_micro')
----> 8 search.fit(X, y)
      9 
     10 # use best classifier to get performance estimate

~/opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.9/site-packages/sklearn/utils/validation.py in inner_f(*args, **kwargs)
     61             extra_args = len(args) - len(all_args)
     62             if extra_args <= 0:
---> 63                 return f(*args, **kwargs)
     64 
     65             # extra_args > 0

~/opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.9/site-packages/sklearn/model_selection/_search.py in fit(self, X, y, groups, **fit_params)
    878             refit_start_time = time.time()
    879             if y is not None:
--> 880                 self.best_estimator_.fit(X, y, **fit_params)
    881             else:
    882                 self.best_estimator_.fit(X, **fit_params)

~/opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.9/site-packages/sklearn/calibration.py in fit(self, X, y, sample_weight)
    301             if n_folds and np.any([np.sum(y == class_) < n_folds
    302                                    for class_ in self.classes_]):
--> 303                 raise ValueError(f"Requesting {n_folds}-fold "
    304                                  "cross-validation but provided less than "
    305                                  f"{n_folds} examples for at least one class.")

ValueError: Requesting 5-fold cross-validation but provided less than 5 examples for at least one class.
```

I am not quite sure how to resolve this error and would truly appreciate any advice.

Thank you in advance!

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please read [ask] and https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/284236. **Why** are you "not quite sure how to resolve this error"? Do you **understand the problem**? For example, do you know what "5-fold cross-validation" *is*? Did you *intend to "request" it*? Do you understand *why* at least 5 examples are necessary? Do you understand *what part of the code provides the examples* for each class? Can you tell how many examples are being provided for each? Do you see where there are not enough?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to check the distribution of your target value `data['character']` : it seems that the number of values in one of the classes in the target column is too small. To do it you can use : `data['character'].value_counts()`

Comment: Thank you so much for your response! I followed your recommendation, and some of the values turned to be like:
```
4947       1
2105       1
6419       1
5959       1
5184       1
1195       1
4169       1
```
If I'm understanding you correctly, these types of values are the ones causing problems, correct? If so, I would appreciate your recommendations on how I may go about fixing this

Comment: You can remove the classes with a low frequency